# topological sort bug python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The output is supposed to be [1,2,5,4,3,7,6] but i am getting [1,2,5,4,7,3,6]...need help to fix the code

```
graph = {1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6], 4: [3, 6, 7], 5: [4, 7], 6: [], 7: [6]}
output_stack = []


def top_dfs_rec(graph1, start, path):
    path = path + [start]
    for edge in graph1[start]:
        if edge not in path:
           path = top_dfs_rec(graph1, edge, path)
    output_stack.insert(0, start)
    return output_stack


print(top_dfs_rec(graph, 1, []))
```

Comment: Are you using python 3 or python 2,7  please decide and delete the wrong tag.

Comment: @Sharku python 3

Comment: Sorry I do not get what you are trying to do. Why do you need that output?

Comment: *Both* of those outputs are valid topological sorts. So why do you expect one over the other?

Comment: You need to provide more details about your data representation and the description of the algorithm you're using.

Comment: I m using dfs to recussively perform topological sort

Comment: @MattMessersmith...i know my output is valid but is there a way i can get the other output too?

Comment: Yes, there is. However, there isn't an easy way to "choose" one over the other, as they are both perfectly valid sorts. Do you want *all* topological sorts instead of *one* topological sort?

Comment: Do you have some other hidden constraints that you're not expressing in the question? Or do you just want a list of all valid topological sorts? Edit the question accordingly. Also, it's best to ask a pointed question, and not ask for help. We know you need help: else you wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: @MattMessersmith i wouldn't mind sir!..lol

Comment: @MattMessersmith well its just that, in the answer key that my teacher has given, the other output is given

Comment: FIrst, I wouldn't be too concerned with the answer key. What you're doing here looks correct (as long as `start` has no incoming edges), your code should always generate a valid topological sort. However, you might want to improve it by *calculating* `start` instead of passing it in. You could also have the top-level interface just take the graph as well, and then call a helper function to create/pass `path` around. Since it's a homework problem, I'm not going to give a direct answer. `start` should always be defined as *some* node which has no incoming edges. HTH, good luck.

Comment: @MattMessersmith Thanks a lot...appreciate your help! but my start does not have any incoming nodes already

Answer (score 0):

Your output, and your desired output differ because of the order of each sub path:

```
for edge in graph1[start]:
```

this will traverse the graph in order. The only way I can think of finding all solutions is to repeat `path = top_dfs_rec(graph1, edge, path)` for each edge coming off of the but store them as different paths, and then continue recursing and de-duplicate. This would be closer to a breadth first search.

Otherwise take a second branch off of your `if edge not in path`:

```
if edge not in path:
    path = top_dfs_rec(graph1, edge, path)
else
    <record alternate valid path>
```

Which is why you don't have 6 appearing twice (it's in each valid path).

Answer (score 0):

From the structure of your graph, the node '3' and '7' are in the same 'layer'.Thus it is randomly that topological sort chooses the node between '3' and '7'.